# I encrypt but cannot perform decoding of file using C++

Tags: c++, file, encryption, xor

Write a cryptographic program that works similarly to my crypto program:• Prompt the user to enter a secret key and use it to compute the seed of a random number generator • Prompt the user to give the names of an input file and the output coded/decoded file• Create the sequence of random bytes from a random number generator with the seed obtained from user’s secret key. • Perform the coding of bit x using a random bit r as follows: x⊕ = r • Since ∀r ∈{0,1}, r ⊕r = 0, perform decoding using the same sequence of random bytes and the same operation x⊕ = r . Decoding is based on the operation x⊕r ⊕r = x⊕(r ⊕r) = x⊕0 = x

Below is the code that works for encryption but when it come to decryption, the cipher text contains only 3 characters. I have not been able to figure why the decoding does not work. I am using Dev-C++. Your help will be very appreciated.

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<conio.h>
  #include<math.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<fstream>

  using namespace std;


  int main()
  {   
    char  n, line[1024],  keystring[100]; char FitoEncr[100], NewFiCrypt[100];
    char FiletobeDecrypted[100];
    ifstream IS ("FitoEncr.txt", ios::in);
    ofstream OS ("NewFiCrypt.txt", ios::out); 

    unsigned int psswd=0, number;
    cout<<"Please, enter a secret key :";
    cin.getline(keystring, 100);
    for( int i=0;keystring[i]!='\0'; i++)

      psswd=(psswd+3)*keystring[i];
    cout<<"initial password: "<<keystring<<endl;
    cout<<"encrypted password: "<<psswd<<endl;

    cout<<"please, enter the name of the input file: ";
    cin.getline(FitoEncr,20);
    cout<<"please, enter the name of the output file: ";
    cin.getline(NewFiCrypt,20);

    srand(psswd);    //not sure about creating the sequence of random bytes from a...
    number=rand() % 255; //random number generator with the seed obtained from user's secret key

   //ENCRYPTION

    while(IS.get(n))
     {
         if(IS.get(n))
         {      
           n^=rand();
           OS<<n;
           cout<<"character coded:"<<n;   
         }

     }
     IS.close();
     OS.close();

    //DECRYPTION

     ifstream IS1;
     ofstream OS1; 

     IS1.open("NewFiCrypt.txt", ios::in);
     OS1.open("FilDecr.txt", ios::out); 

     while(IS1.get(n))
     {
       if(IS1.get(n))
       {      
         n^=rand();  //I think the problem starts on this line...
         OS1<<n;
         cout<<"character coded:"<<n;   
       }

     }       
     IS1.close();
     OS1.close();     

     getch();

     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Print out the values as they're being processed, AND the values the RNG is generating, and you'll probably spot your error. At the very least, you can tell us where it's diverging so we can help you efficiently. Rather than using `<<` on a char that might be non-printable (e.g. 0-31, 127-255), perhaps change `<<n` to `<< (int)n` so you can see what's happening. Ernest is right by the way - you should reseed the RNG.

Comment: The question reads like homework.  If it is, then you should flag it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seed the random number generator before encrypting, but not before decrypting, so the series of random numbers will be different; obviously they would have to be the same for this to work. If you add another

```
srand(psswd);
```

before the decryption second, that will get you closer.

On closer inspection, though, there are some significant other problems. For example, each time you call `get(n)`, you consume a character from your input file. You're calling `get(n)` in your while loop conditions, but then immediately calling it again in your `if`; that means you'll effectively be skipping every other character on input and again on output; the decrypted file would then end up with just 25% of the characters from the original file! Just remove the `if` statements altogether, and your loop will be right. Hopefully having fixed both of these things your program will work.

Comment: I thought that we should use srand(value) only one time in the program? Anyway, I tried to seed again before decrytion, but i still have the same result.

Comment: You seed it to make it start from a specific point in its sequence. Here you obviously need it to start from the same place on both sets of operations, so you need to call it twice.

Comment: I removed the if statement, but I don't see  how to change my while loop, although, I am obtaining a decoded file with only half the data.

Comment: @T4000, did you remove *both* `if` statements? You need to remove them both; the `while` loops themselves are fine.

Comment: Yes, I did remove both if statements. But I only obtain half of the data. I am still trying to fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should first check what it writes in the file without the n ^= rand(); line. Without it, it should just copy the file right?

Comment: Same result even without n^=rand().

Comment: You are doing a while(IS.get(n)) so why do you check if(IS.get(n))? Also the line with "//random number generator" just assigns a number from 0-255 to variable named number and it isn't used anywhere.